# Postgres: Find missing items in a version table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Table in Postgres 12 which tracks what Items i are use in which Versions v:

```
CREATE TABLE compare_test(v BIGINT, i BIGINT);
```

With example data:

```
INSERT INTO compare_test VALUES
 (1,21),
 (1,22),
 (1,23),
 (2,21),
 (2,22),
 (2,23),
 (3,21),
 (3,22);
```

I'm trying to create a View that returns:

| source_v | target_v | source_i | target_i |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 23 | null |
| 2 | 3 | 23 | null |

Queries used to compare missing values in two Tables like:

```
SELECT l.v as source_v, l.i as source_i,
           r.v as target_v, r.i as target_i
  FROM compare_test l
    LEFT JOIN
        compare_test r ON r.i = l.i
  WHERE r.i IS NULL;
```

and

```
SELECT l.v as source_v, l.i as source_i
  FROM compare_test l
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (
        SELECT i as target_i
          FROM compare_test r
          WHERE r.i = l.i
      )
```

do not seem to work if the joined Table is the same Table or if more than 2 Versions are in the Table.

I don't have the option to change the Database Structure but I can use plugins.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not so clear, what you try to achieve

Comment: What is source and target?

Comment: Some of the versions in the table do not have all items and I want a diff between all versions. see the table in the question for an example. v 3 is missing item 3 so it contains a row for v1 has item 3 but v3 not and a row for v2 has item 1 but v3 not.

Comment: source is the version that has the item target is the version where the item is missing.

Comment: (1,3), (2,2), (3,1) , what is the expected output?

Comment: I changed the example data/output to make it easier to understand by not using the same numbers for v and i. @Serg the expected output for the example data is the table in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below gives those results.
It makes re-use of a CTE.

*(but somehow I got a feeling that there should exist a more efficient way)*

```
with cte1 as (
  SELECT i
  , count(*) cnt
  , min(v) min_v
  , max(v) max_v
  FROM compare_test
  GROUP BY i
)
, cte2 as
(
  select *
  from cte1 as c1
  where not exists (
    select 1
    from cte1 c2
    where c2.min_v = c1.min_v
      and c2.max_v < c1.max_v
   ) 
) 
select distinct
  t.v as source_v
, c1.max_v as target_v
, c2.i as source_i
, null as target_i
from cte2 c2
left join compare_test t
  on t.i = c2.i
left join cte1 c1
  on t.v between c1.min_v and c1.max_v
  and c1.i != t.i
order by source_v
```

But if it's not really required to follow the relations, then it becomes really simple.
Then it's just a left join of the existing to all possible combinations.

> ```
> select distinct 
>   src.v as source_v
> , missing.v as target_v
> , src.i as source_i
> , missing.i as target_i
> from
> (
>   select ver.v, itm.i
>   from (select distinct v from compare_test) as ver
>   cross join (select distinct i from compare_test) as itm
>   left join compare_test t
>     on t.v = ver.v and t.i = itm.i
>   where t.v is null
> ) as missing
> left join compare_test as src
>   on src.i = missing.i and src.v != missing.v
> order by target_i, target_v, source_v
> ```
>
> ```
> source_v | target_v | source_i | target_i
> -------: | -------: | -------: | -------:
>        1 |        5 |       21 |       21
>        2 |        5 |       21 |       21
>        3 |        5 |       21 |       21
>        1 |        5 |       22 |       22
>        2 |        5 |       22 |       22
>        3 |        5 |       22 |       22
>        1 |        3 |       23 |       23
>        2 |        3 |       23 |       23
>        1 |        5 |       23 |       23
>        2 |        5 |       23 |       23
>        5 |        1 |       44 |       44
>        5 |        2 |       44 |       44
>        5 |        3 |       44 |       44
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4ffb9168f69acb62d81bfcf88aa2dea8)*

Comment: It works for the given example set, but if I add additional data, for example (5,44) it returns just one new row with (5,null,44,null). The new row is wrong in it self because the target_v column is null, also I would expect 11 new rows. One for each i of the other versions because v 5 is missing i 21-23 and one each for v 1-3 because they are missing i 44.

Comment: @Coruu That actually simplified things a lot. Although I don't really see the point of multiplying the missing with the existing.  See update.

Comment: the idea was to make a view out of this and than filter on a source_v and a target_v to get the difference between only this two. I know this would be easier to do as a function but we use some software on top that expect a table or view with the data und will not work with a function.